# Click on button (with Tablet) don"t work

Tags: asp.net

I have problem with click button in tablet.Problem is when i press first time on button i get button:hover and that when i press again on this button it do the event.
(First touch making button hovered and Second make the event)
I need to do some kind double click to do the event or to disable button:hover(i don"t want this solution).
Or i need to check if this (first)click come from Tablet then i can to disable button:hover but only to Tablet users to Pc
Can any 1 know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Or i need to check if this (first)click come from Tablet then i can to disable button:hover but only to Tablet users to Pc